# iOS 11 & Apple Maps: Hide Search Box in Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, mail.app, search, ios

I’m not sure what that box is called, but it’s the one with the search at the top of it, and the history below.

In Portrait Orientation you can swipe down on it and it reduces to a single search box. It’s annoying how much space it takes up, but at least it doesn’t cover half the screen.

In Landscape Orientation, I can’t see any way to reduce the search box, so that it always covers half of the screen. The main reason to use Landscape Orientation is to see *more* horizontally, not *less*.

Is there any way to get rid of that search box?

I have iOS 11.1 on an iPhone X, but the problem also occurs on iPhone 6 etc.

Comment: I have the same iPhone and iOS.  The box does cover 1/3 of the screen but after you enter your destination and start your route, the box disappears and just becomes a small rectangle on the bottom.  It doesn't cover the screen anymore.

Comment: @fsb That only works if you’re using directions. I just want to look at the map.

Comment: I haven't found any way to move/remove the box while looking at the map.  I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: @Dennis This is obviously some strange usage of the word “feature” that I wasn’t previously aware of. I have submitted this as a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. I have no solution, but believe this is a software issue that is exclusive to "narrow" iPhones (i.e., anything but the Plus) running iOS 11.

I have been using both an iPhone 8 Plus and an iPhone X for the past week, and have noticed this issue only exists on the X. On the 8 Plus, I am easily able to close the search box in landscape mode. On the X, I cannot. I have tried deleting Maps and re-installing, but with no change. It's almost as if the bottom of the search box on the X runs off the bottom of the screen, and that's the problem.

I've also tried a friend's 8, and an old 6, but running iOS 11, and both devices have the same issue -- can't close the search box in landscape mode. However, trying this on an iPhone 5 running iOS 10, and it's not an issue (in landscape mode, the box remains to the bottom of the screen, not the side, and compresses to the bottom).

It would be useful to hear from (1) people running iPhone SE or 5S using iOS 11 and (2) people running a 6/6S/7 under iOS 10 and see if this is an issue, to confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have submitted this as a bug report, in that it doesn’t appear to apply to all phones.